# Can't find ScanWhenAssociated, Other way to disable auto-network-scan

Tags: windows, network-adapter, wifi-configuration, lag

I have a Problem with my Asus AC 56 WiFi USB Stick: I have lag spikes. The only solution to fix those spikes was to turn off the auto-network-scan of Windows. It's pretty inconvenient, because I have to run a script after the boot up of Windows to turn the auto scan on, and then off so I don't have to do open the cmd prompt and so on...

Now the thing I'm searching for: I found something about the Reg-Key "ScanWhenAssociated". There are many posts about it ([this one for example](https://communities.intel.com/thread/73830)) . You have to find the name of your device in one of the folders inside of one,but I wasn't able to do for mine. Then in the folder of the device you own, there should be the Reg-Key "ScanWhenAssociated". Although this might fix the problem too, is there a possibility to only let Windows scan for networks when you are connected to none?